# Why aren't the members of my nested companion object automatically visible in the class?

Tags: scala, import, nested

Suppose I have this Scala code:

```
object Outer {

  object Inner {
    val B = "B"
  }
  class Inner {
    def b = B
  }
}
```

I would expect this to compile, but `B` cannot be accessed from the definition of `b`. I need to add `import Inner._` in `class Inner`to make it work. Why is that? Is the companion object `Inner` not defined correctly?

Comment: I came here *again* (after having forgotten the thing), showing how important this issue might be for newcomers. I think the 'Outer' plays no role in the question; it's quite the same even without it. Thanks for asking this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just not supposed to work this way - using `import Inner._` is a consistent behavior.

---

Generally, companion object is needed, if you want to achieve the behavior similar to static members in Java. Scala way is to move all static members away to a singleton object, with the benefit that private/protected memebers of a companion class can be accessed from it:

```
object Outer {

  object Inner {
    def print(inner: Inner) = inner.B // compiles!
  }    
  class Inner {
    private val B = "B"
  }    
}
```

You can use companion object as a factory for the class with a private constructor:

```
scala> object Outer {
     |
     |   object Inner {
     |     def newInstance = new Inner()
     |   }
     |   class Inner private() {
     |     private val B = "B"
     |   }
     | }
defined module Outer

scala> Outer.Inner.newInstance
res1: Outer.Inner = Outer$Inner@431693

scala> new Outer.Inner
<console>:7: error: constructor Inner cannot be accessed in object $iw
       new Outer.Inner
       ^
```

Comment: I would like to define B as a constant, used in class Outer.Inner and also accessible to the outside world as Outer.Inner.B.  I was under the impression that I didn't need the import if Inner wasn't nested, but I see that I was mistaken, because my example doesn't compile either if I delete the Outer class... So what's the bets way to define constants, similar to the `public static final String B = "B";` that I'd write in Java?

Comment: OK, I just needed confirmation that I do need the extra import. That's fine by me; i was just thinking that the members were automatically imported in companion objects/classes.

Answer (score 11):

If the members of the companion object would be imported into the class, it would pollute the namespace of the class without the programmer being able to controle it. This might not be that bad (but still bad) with values but I really wouldn't want to see that with functions.

Just think about `apply()` or functions you inherit from traits (both cases where you can't just change the name without loosing something). If these functions where automatically imported into your classes namespace, the compiler wouldn't know which one to use. So if the class and the object had a function `func()` you would end up writing `this.func()` in your classes code just to make sure which one to call.

So see it as a possibility to keep your namespace clean. You can still pollute it by  using `import Inner._`

Comment: Good justification of why you need the import. Makes a lot of sense.